# h:selectOneMenu doe not work after Myfaces upgradation from 1.1.4 to 1.1.8

Tags: myfaces

Iam using JSF 1 and trying to update Myfaces version from 1.1.4 to 1.1.8
I have something like this in myxhtml page,

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="orgCountry"  value="#{crud.orgAddress.country}
<f:selectItem itemLabel="#{messageResources.dropDownPleaseSelect}" itemValue=""/>
<f:selectItem itemLabel="#{crud.usrbld.countryName}" itemValue="#{crud.usrbld.countryId}"/>
<f:selectItems value="#{getSelectItems('countryDAOCrud')}"/>
<a4j:support id="countryDropDown" event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true" reRender="orgState" oncomplete="updateStateDropdown()"/>
```

</h:selectOneMenu>

and getselectItems is a normal method,

```
getselectItems (){
 list= gettingfromDB
 converting into selectItem type
```

And country is a normal pojo class with hash and equals method

When Myfaces 1.1.4 is used, everything works fine but when upgraded to Myfaces 1.1.8,
My submit is failing,and that is due to the validation error,which says,
ParametrizableFacesMessage "{0}": Value is not a valid option.
The cause for this error is the matchvalue method in _SelectItemUtil which is,

```
Object itemValue = item.getValue();
                if (value==itemValue || (itemValue.equals(value)))
                {
                    return true;
                }
```

So here the value is the selected value from dropdown and itemValue is one of the items of SelectItem (this is in Iterator Loop), here the value is of my class type and itemValue is string and since they never match validation always fails.
Whereas in Myfaces 1.1.4 the itemValue is converted to class object type and thus the comparison returns success.
I would not be able to upgrade JSF version.
Can anybody please help me in resolving the issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had to overwrite the jar method to solve this problem